# Change dropdown depending on the choice of 2 other dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Hi and thank you for your time.

I am trying to make it so when the user selects 2 different dropdown options it determines the 3rd dropdown.

I have already created a codepen/fiddle.

http://codepen.io/brynhowlet/pen/EyYQyG?editors=1010

```
See codepen for details.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be great to use css selectors to select each radio element: element = document.querySelector(selectors);

Comment: in your code there is no radio button given and you haven't tried anything? at least try some jquery things na

Comment: radio button or dropdown?? question and codepen you have posted kinda looks unrelated

Comment: Please don't ask us to visit other sites to see your problem. Instead, create a [mcve] and [edit] it into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood it, you want to show the options in 3rd Dropdown based on the selection of first 2 dropdowns.

If that is true, my idea would be keep the relation of first 2 dropdowns in the options of 3rd dropdown with some reference so that they can relate to each other, I prefer using `data-` attribute in HTML.

And then on selection of both the dropdowns, filter what needs to be shown in the result dropdown and show options accordingly.

Example: is given below.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#sheet, #color").change(function(){
   var sheet = $("#sheet").val();
    var color = $("#color").val();
    
    // Find All Option in product dropdown excluding the default one
    var $prodOptions = $("option", "#product").filter(":not('[disabled]')");
    
    // Filter Options on change of dropdowns
    var $filtered = $prodOptions.filter(function(){
     return $(this).data("sheet") === sheet && $(this).data("color") === color;
    });
    
    $prodOptions.hide(); // hide all on change
    $filtered.show(); // show the filtered ones
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br> 1.)
<select id="sheet">
  <option disabled selected value="">please make a selection</option>
  <option value="white">smooth white</option>
  <option value="natural">smooth natural</option>
</select>
<br> 2.)
<select id="color">
  <option disabled selected value="">please make a selection</option>
  <option value="natural">orkney natural</option>
  <option value="white">orkney white</option>
  <option value="black">orkney black</option>
  <option value="charcoal">orkney charcoal</option>
  <option value="indigo">orkney indigo</option>
</select>
<hr>
<select id="product">
  <option disabled value="select one to preview">select one to preview</option>
  <option data-sheet="white" data-color="natural" value="natural (white sheets)">natural (white sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="natural" data-color="natural" value="natural (natural sheets)">natural (natural sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="white" data-color="white" value="white (white sheets)">white (white sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="natural" data-color="white" value="white (natural sheets)">white (natural sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="white" data-color="black" value="black (white sheets)">black (white sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="natural" data-color="black" value="black (natural sheets)">black (natural sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="white" data-color="charcoal" value="charcoal (white sheets)">charcoal (white sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="natural" data-color="charcoal" value="charcoal (natural sheets)">charcoal (natural sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="white" data-color="indigo" value="indigo (white sheets)">indigo (white sheets)</option>
  <option data-sheet="natural" data-color="indigo" value="indigo (natural sheets)">indigo (natural sheets)</option>
</select>
```

Added in jsfiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/sqavj95p/

Comment: Thank you this helped a great deal

Comment: pleasures all mine... Happy coding!!